# pip install --user doesn't work on Debian 12

Tags: pip, debian, pipenv

I'm trying to install some packages in my home directory, and I'm unable to do so.

I want to install pipenv, using `pip install pipenv --user`, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

```
error: externally-managed-environment

× This environment is externally managed
╰─> To install Python packages system-wide, try apt install
    python3-xyz, where xyz is the package you are trying to
    install.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian-packaged Python package,
    create a virtual environment using python3 -m venv path/to/venv.
    Then use path/to/venv/bin/python and path/to/venv/bin/pip. Make
    sure you have python3-full installed.
    
    If you wish to install a non-Debian packaged Python application,
    it may be easiest to use pipx install xyz, which will manage a
    virtual environment for you. Make sure you have pipx installed.
    
    See /usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv for more information.

note: If you believe this is a mistake, please contact your Python installation or OS distribution provider. You can override this, at the risk of breaking your Python installation or OS, by passing --break-system-packages.
```

Now, I understand that this is supposed to avoid breaking system packages, which are installed by the package manager. What I don't understand is why am I unable to install any package in my home directory?

Answer (score 1):

Installing packages in your home directory can also break system packages so that's why it's disabled too. I just ran into this with a simple wake on lan script which uses the wakeonlan module from PyPI.

I just did what they suggest, I created a venv, installed wakeonlan there and modified the script shebang to point to python inside that venv.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, you can run pip with `--break-system-packages`:

```
pip install pipenv --user --break-system-packages
```

To easiest way to get back the old pre-Debian12 behaviour just for your user, is to add `break-system-packages = true` in the `[global]` section of your `~/.config/pip/pip.conf`, as noted in `/usr/share/doc/python3.11/README.venv`:

> This can be overriden by passing the --break-system-packages option to pip. You
> do this at your own risk: pip may break Python modules that part of your Debian
> system depends on. This option can also be specified by exporting
> PIP_BREAK_SYSTEM_PACKAGES=1 or configuring the following in
> ~/.config/pip/pip.conf or /etc/pip.conf:
>
> ```
> [global]
> break-system-packages = true
> ```

See also the final note:

> A clean option is to install your own Python (from source) in /usr/local, that
> isn't EXTERNALLY-MANAGED.

Answer (score 0):

sudo rm /usr/lib/python3.11/EXTERNALLY-MANAGED

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).